# AVD Manager - No system image installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-automotive

I have downloaded the Canary version (Android Studio 4.2 Canary2) of Android Studio and can able to create Automotive Emulator for default device. When I tried to create for edited version(cloned version of default device) of Automotive emulator, it shows System image not available.

Please look into my sdk setup below.

[image: SDK PLATFORMS]
[image: CLONED DEVICE]
[image: SYSTEM IMAGE NOT AVAILABLE]
[image: SDK TOOLS]
[image: SDK UPDATE SITES]

Answer (score 0):

I have used Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image with revision ***4*** and the issue is resolved.
If I use  Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image with revision ***5***, then No system image is available for selection.

[Revision 4 download link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/x86-28_r04.zip)

After downloading copy the files to below SDK path
C:\Users%user%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\android-automotive\x86

Answer (score 0):

For the Polestar image, you need to select the SDK Platforms tab and then check the show package details checkbox bottom right.

Then scroll to the Android 9 section and enable Polestar 2 there. This will install the image and then in the AVD you will be able to choose automotive and Polestar.

[image]

Also make sure you see the play store logo. If not, reboot android studio first.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kenny, Normally I can create emulator. My question over here is, for edited version (cloned version of default device) of Automotive emulator, it shows System image not available. AVD --> Create Virtual Device --> New Hardware Profile --> Select Automotive and change the resolution.